# Double build output when using NgcWebpackPlugin

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-2, angular2-aot

The [Angular Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter) output surprises me:

[image]

Why do I see the "src" twice?

In my much larger project, I see the same thing:

[image]

Here's my NgcWebpackPlugin config:

```
return new ngcWebpack.NgcWebpackPlugin({
  disabled: false,
  tsConfig: resolve('tsconfig.webpack.json'),
  resourceOverride: resolve('app/src/empty.ts')
});
```